# why chrome fails to open page http://0:80/

Tags: google-chrome, ip

The ip `0` is the simplest alias I've found to localhost, and most browsers can open the page `http://0/` without problem.

When trying the same on Chrome, it always redirect me to the search page.. like it does not recognize that `0`, `0:80`, `127.1`, o `127.1:80` are valid IPs -- although it ask if you meant `0.0.0.0` or `127.0.0.1`

Chrome can, however, open the page `http://0.0.0.0` correctly

Answer (score 0):

Every HTTP URL consists of the following, in the given order. Several schemes other than HTTP also share this general format, with some variation.

- the scheme name (commonly called protocol, although not every URL scheme is a protocol, e.g. `mailto` is not a protocol);
- a colon, two slashes;
- a host, normally given as a domain name but sometimes as a literal IP address;
- optionally a colon followed by a port number;
- the full path of the resource;

The scheme says how to connect, the host specifies where to connect, and the remainder specifies what to ask for.

For programs such as Common Gateway Interface (CGI) scripts, this is followed by a query string and an optional fragment identifier.

The syntax is:

```
scheme://domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id
```

So basically `http` is valid scheme, `://` are valid colon and two slashes, but `0` is not valid domain name or IP address. However, the `http://0.0.0.0` **are** valid scheme and literal IP address, that's why Google Chrome opens it.

The **domain name or literal numeric IP address** gives the destination location for the URL. A literal numeric IPv6 address may be given, but must be enclosed in `[ ]` e.g. `[db8:0cec::99:123a]`

The fact that other browsers "convert" `http://0/` into `localhost` or `127.x.x.x` is just browser implementation, it is **not** by the standard.

More details:

- [IETF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761#section-6.3) and [IETF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1466)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator)

Comment: I know it sounds odds, but *ping* works fine with `127.0.0.1`, `127.1`,  as much as `2130706433` and all of them point to `localhost` -- note that `2130706433 = 127*256^3 + 1` -- so I guess this method will work with any IP